# How to create factors variables based on ranges of a column (i.e., <15,15-30,etc...)

Tags: r

I am doing homework for school based on 'nycflights13' data in RStudio and I need to create a factor variable (calling it delaylevel) that separates dep_delay into 4 categories (<15 min, 15 - 30 min, 30 - 60 min, <60 min) based off another filter variable that I already created (shown below) called flight1 and call this new variable flight2.

After I do this I need to find what proportion were delayed 15 min or more based on flt2 using group_by w/ origin and delaylevel where I must 'eliminate missing delaylevel and summarize function to count'. (I believe I know how to do this part but am having trouble with the 1st part)

Any help would be appreciated.

Needed: tidyverse package and nycflights13 package (flights)

Comment: Look at `help("cut")`

Comment: `cut` can do this. Another option is a `case_when` statement. Remember that `case_when` evaluates the statements in order and exits at the first `TRUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to play around with the upper and lower bounds of the breaks argument because anything outside of the minimum and maximum break gets coerced to NA. If you want to have nicer looking factor levels you can use the `labels` argument

```
cut(fit1, breaks=c(0,15,30,60,1000))
```